# Linq: Get a List with a guaranteed length?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a method which should always return 5 Elements. Unfortunately, the input might be less than 5. How can I force Linq to always return 5 Elements?

e.g

```
public List<byte> GetFrob(List<int> maybeFrobs)
{
var result = maybeFrobs.Select(x => x.ToByte().ToList();
// can I extend the result to 5 elements, if less than 5?
return result;
}
```

Comment: What do you each element to be if the input is less than 5? The default of the type?

Comment: If there aren't enough values append or prepend?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to clarify what you want to happen. I.e. I have list that I want to pad by *Append*ing infinite sequence of 0/`default(T)` and than *Take* desired number of elements (i.e. 5)".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can generate a list of 5 "default" elements, then concat that to the end of your input collection.

```
IEnumerable<int> defaultElements = Enumerable.Repeat(0, 5);

List<byte> result = maybeFrobs
    .Concat(defaultElements)
    .Take(5)
    .Select(x => x.ToByte())
    .ToList();
```

By concating the collections then `Take`ing, you are guaranteed to have *exactly* 5 elements in by the time you hit `Select`.

Replace the `0` in `Repeat` with whatever you want the default element to be.

Comment: Thanks, both obvious and a good idea.
Memory could be a problem but I have some basic bytes and a low count so it's not a concern (at least, serialising 200mb objects to JSON and back for shits and giggles dwarfs this)

Answer (score 8):

> I have a method which should always return 5 Elements

You current implementation does not always return 5 elements also (in case if the original list length is more than 5).

You can always append a sequence and then use `Take(5)` (or in case if prepend is needed - swap the collections and use `TakeLast`):

```
public List<byte> GetFrob(List<int> maybeFrobs) => maybeFrobs
    .Select(x1 => x1.ToByte())
    .Concat(Enumerable.Repeat<byte>(0, 5)) // or use any other "default" source
    .Take(5)
    .ToList();
```

If the logic is "at least" - the implementation can be easily updated, for example:

```
private const int atLeast = 5; 
public List<byte> GetFrob(List<int> maybeFrobs) => maybeFrobs
    .Select(x1 => x1.ToByte())
    .Concat(Enumerable.Repeat<byte>(0, atLeast))
    .Take(Math.Max(maybeFrobs.Count, atLeast))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, both obvious and a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to `yield return` the exact number of converted elements that you need from the source list, and then `yield return` the exact number of remaining (default) bytes:

```
public static IEnumerable<byte> GetFrob(List<int> source, int targetCount)
{
    var itemCountFromSource = Math.Min(source.Count, targetCount);

    for (var i = 0; i < itemCountFromSource; i++)
    {
        yield return source[i].ToByte();
    }
    
    for (var i = itemCountFromSource; i < targetCount; i++)
    {
        yield return default(byte);
    }
}
```

Seeing as the method returns an `IEnumerable`, you will need to create a `List` from the return value:

```
const int targetCount = 5;

var maybeFrobs = new List<int> { 254, 188, 203 };

var list = GetFrob(maybeFrobs, targetCount).ToList();
```